# Where to put Perl script in Laravel project

Tags: perl, laravel

I have a Perl script I am using that scrapes data and saves it to my SQLite DB for my Laravel project. I have verified that the script works.

I will be setting up a scheduled task to run this every day [so my DB has the latest information].

My question is - where should I put this Perl script within my Laravel project directory, and following that, how would I call this script using Laravel's [task scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling)?

Note: note, I am fully aware I probably shouldn't be mixing languages within my Laravel project, but I am working under a time constraint for a hackathon, so I am making use of my time with what works.  Trying to hack together anything that works...

Comment: Then `hacks/sorty_about_the_perl.pl` is it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I.e. you can create a subdirectory, let's say `scripts`, in the Laravel's `storage` directory and put your perl script(s) in there.

Then you can schedule its execution like this

```php
$schedule->exec('/usr/bin/perl '.storage_path('scripts/myscript.pl'))
    ->daily()
    ->at('09:00');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. Is it good/bad practice to use scripts from other languages in Laravel?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I'd tend to say anything you can write in Perl you can probably write in PHP, and doing so will benefit you by having the rest of the app's functionality available to it.

Comment: @ceejayoz if this script simply interfaces with my DB, does it need to be a Model? Or is it fine as simply a script?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage It should not be a model (although it might interact with some). It should be [a command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands).

Comment: @theGreenCabbage IMHO it's perfectly fine to use scripts written in other languages when you understand what you're doing and all implications of this decision.

Comment: @peterm I agree it's fine. If it's trivially rewritten in PHP, though, taking advantage of all the Laravel functionality like centralized logging, email, etc. that you'd have to reimplement in Perl if you needed it probably tips the scales.

Comment: @peterm The script goes to a site and recursively scrapes everything relevant to what I need to saves it to a table in my SQLite DB. What would the implications be, for example, in that it's a Perl script? I did conform to Laravel-y standards by creating a migration script for the DB table creation instead of having Perl add a table for me (if it doesn't exist).